# Prevent being timed out on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, timeout

We are all working at home presently and so heightened *physical* security of our computing devices is not our first or seventh concern.  I have a new macbookPro  with `macOS Catalina` and latest `chrome`

```
Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)
```

and have noticed that I am being signed out. Now I see it being *explicitly stated* :

[image]

How can this timeout be disabled or made infinite?

Comment: Were you logged out of your account? It never happened with me.

Comment: ( 1 ) I had been logged in. ( 2 ) Due to some (new?) security-related timeout mechanism I was auto-logged out *by*  _chrome_